# References for deep understanding of correlation matrices

Tags: correlation

Can anyone suggest some references for learning as much as possible (and in detail!) about correlation matrixes?

In particular, would be great to have (among others) covered:

- algebraic and statistical properties
- matrix factorization
- estimation

Unfortunately, I could not find any comprehensive source that treats all these topics (sort of "from zero to hero in correlation matrixes").